# Theoretical variance of the (binary) accuracy score for a random guesser

Tags: variance, binary-data, accuracy

Suppose we want to compute accuracy for a binary classifier (assuming balanced classes):

Acc = (TP+TN)/N

Where N = TP + TN + FP + FN.

For the case of a pure random guesser where each (actual) positive and negative sample has an equal chance of being correctly or incorrectly classified, we have that E(TP)=N/4=E(TN)=N/4, then it is simple to verify that E(Acc)= E[(TP+TN)/N]=(1/N)(N/4+N/4)=1/2.

So, if E(Acc)=1/2 for a pure (uniform) random guesser, How can we compute the theoretical value for Var[Acc]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you classify $N$ samples and have a 50% chance of being correct each time, your TP+TN is a [binomially distributed random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) $X$ with parameters $n=N$ and $p=\frac{1}{2}$. Wikipedia tells us that

$$ \text{Var}(X)=np(1-p)=\frac{N}{4}.$$

So

$$ \text{Var}(\text{Acc}) = \text{Var}\bigg(\frac{X}{N}\bigg)=\frac{1}{N^2}\text{Var}(X) =\frac{1}{4N}.$$

Also, [accuracy is not a good evaluation measure](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352).

Comment: Hello Stephan, thanks very much for your reply, it makes sense. Yes, I am very aware that using accuracy has many drawbacks. Nevertheless, I took a look at the link you shared and found comments you wrote there very enlightening. About my question, I was just wondering how we could characterize statistically the classical ACC in case of a pure (random) guesser. So, if I may, could we extrapole the expression you wrote above for n_classes > 2? For example...

Comment: For the uniform random guesser, if p=1/n_classes, by using the binomial formla Var(X)=np(1-p), then Var(X)=N*(1/n_clases)(1 - (1/n_classses)). By using this expression for Var(X) for Var(Acc), we would then arrive at Var(Acc) = (1/N)*(1/(n_clases))*(1 - (1/n_classses)), indicating that Var(Acc) decreases as n_classes increases by a factor given by (1/(n_clases))*(1 - (1/n_classses)) ?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, although I have to admit that I don't quite know how enlightening the variance of the accuracy of a random classifier on $n$ equiprobable classes is...

Comment: Hello Stephan, thanks again for your reply. I agree that using the accuracy is not the best choice of classification metric. But in many projects (specially in the industry, as in my case), the metrics are decided in a "top-down" manner, so using accuracy is a requirement defined in the contract, for eg. It's common too that we need to define a baseline reference of bad performance, in this case would be a random uniform guesser. Thus, given the sample size N, I need to compute the theoretical fluctuation of ACC_baseline around the mean value as reference for project documentation...

Comment: Thanks, that also makes sense. I have had my experience with imposed evaluation metrics, and I agree (and often argue) that comparing a method's performance to an extremely simple benchmark should always be done - in my case of forecasting, one should always check whether one improved on a random walk or historical mean forecast, which can be surprisingly hard.